# DataGrid SortDirection ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, sortdirection

I want to specify a default ordering at startup, but still allow the user to sort by clicking on the column headers. Sadly the SortDirection property is ignored when it is set - i.e. we get the correct column header arrow, but nothing is sorted.

Clicking on the headers manually, sorts the data correctly, so it's not the sorting itself. This is the simplified version I'm using:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=CurrentView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding ApplicationName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" 
               Binding="{Binding TotalTime}" SortDirection="Descending"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Update: I also tried adding SortDescriptions to the ICollectionView as proposed, without good results. Could this have something to do with the fact that I'm dynamically adding new items to the collection? I.e. at startup the list is empty and slowly filled and maybe the sortdescription is only applied once?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/5-more-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid)

From above link:

> DataGridColumn.SortDirection does not actually sort the column.
> DataGridColumn.SortDirection is used to queue the visual arrow in the DataGridColumnHeader to point up, down, or to not show.  To actually sort the columns other than clicking on the DataGridColumnHeader, you can set the DataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions programmatically.

Comment: Tried that both with `datagrid.Items` and the actual ICollectionView I'm using, but the results are both the same: negative :(

Comment: On second thought: Maybe this has something to do with me dynamically adding new items to the list?

Comment: @Voo you may want to look at this [MSDN Blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c943e22e-5fdf-469d-9e92-fa0167dc9d62). Essentialy save the SortDescription and reapply it to force a resort.

Comment: Thanks for your help - turns out your first idea was right anyhow, I just got the property and header names confused and wpf has no problems sorting with non existent properties sigh. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any personal experience with this, but I found [this rather helpful article](http://waxtadpole.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/wpf-setting-default-sort-order-for-datagrid-without-using-a-static-resource/).

Essentially you need to add a [SortDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions.aspx) to the CollectionViewSource that the DataGrid is bound to.

Comment: You create a CVS and add the sort direction to that, not the ObservableCollection. OC's use the Move method to sort rows.

Comment: @Xcalibur I fear my wpf/xaml/whatever lingo is a bit limited, so could you translate that? Anyways I tried adding SortDescriptions to both the `datagrid.Items` and the ICollectionView the datagrid is using as source without success.

Comment: Here as well, so that's not lost: Could this have something to do with me dynamically adding new items to the list?

Comment: Sorry Voo, no problem. I was just pointing out that you would add the SortDescription to a CollectionViewSource, not an ObservableCollection. Microsoft goes into this in detail here under "Sorting items in a DataGrid": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx

Comment: Glad to help. I think you have the right idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Turned out that was the solution all along, I just confused the Property and ColumnHeader names - sorry for that. That's why I don't like working with strings :(

Answer (score 3):

This article was very helpful.  I was able to use it to find a somewhat easy solution.  Here is a snippet of my solution that worked.

**XAML**

```
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding LogLister.Logs}"              
            IsReadOnly="True" >

            <DataGrid.Columns>                  

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TimeStampLocal}" Header="Time" x:Name="ColTimeStamp" />

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="Text"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Code**

```
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ViewModel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(LogViewerViewModel), typeof(LogViewerControl),
           new UIPropertyMetadata(null,pf_viewModelChanged));

    private static void pf_viewModelChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (LogViewerControl)o;

        control.ColTimeStamp.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;

        var vm = e.NewValue as LogViewerViewModel;

        if (vm != null)
        {   
            ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(vm.LogLister.Logs);
            collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("TimeStampLocal", ListSortDirection.Descending));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The short of it is that there is no quick, easy way to do it. I wrote my own custom sorter that uses the Move method on ObservableCollections. I override the "DataGridSorting" event and call my own methods to facilitate this. I am not going to post the code here because I think it's too overblown for your question.

I would say stick with my above comment by using a CollectionViewSource and a SortDescription (competent_tech originally posted).