# datagrid default sort and get value

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

In my WPF project, I have a datagrid which looks like:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dgConfig" BorderThickness="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10,15" ItemsSource="{Binding ModulesView, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="14" Background="White">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamName" Binding="{Binding ParamName}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamValue" Binding="{Binding ParamValue}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="DefaultValue" Binding="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaxValue" Binding="{Binding MaxValue}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="MinValue" Binding="{Binding MinValue}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And now I want to get the **Row** value of `ParamValue`. In this case, I need to put the `ParamValue` into `registerArray` in the order of `Address`, so how should I set the `Datagrid` displayed in the order of `Address` and then put the `ParamValue` into **Array** `registerArray` in the order of `Address`? Many thanks!

--------------------------------update------------------------------------------

Define ModulesView:

```
    public ICollectionView ModulesView
    {
        get { return _ModulesView; }
        set
        {
            _ModulesView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Use ModulesView:

```
    private void RefreshModule()
    {
        ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(sdb.GetModules())
        {
            Filter = obj =>
            {
                var Module = (Module)obj;
                return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module.ModelNumber;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: 2 questions, first how did you populate your datagrid, from code-behind or using the ItemsSource "ModulesView"? Second, your sorting should already be set correctly since you used `SortDirection="Ascending"` on your Address column.

Comment: First I use `ICollectionView ModulesView` in the **ViewModel** to populate datagrid, and second I don't know why but the data in the **Row** `Address` didn't default sorted untill I click the Row Header.

Comment: For the sorting problem, would it be an acceptable alternative to sort the items before setting ItemsSource, by `OrderBy()`? That way you won't have to rely on the Datagrid sorting. [DataGrid SortDirection ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556302/datagrid-sortdirection-ignored). Also you have a small typo `Header="Addrsss"` should be `Header="Address"`

Comment: And as for your `ParamValue` question, is there something like a button users can click, and that should trigger `registerArray` to be filled? If so, you can just use `registerArray = ModulesView.OrderBy(mod => mod.Address).Select(mod => mod.ParamValue).ToArray();` at any point of your code to get the array. Note that you would need `using System.Linq;` for that.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Sorry, but ite seems that my ModulesView can not call OrderBy method.

Comment: Hi, could you post your code for `ModulesView`? `ICollectionView` is usually bound to a List, or ObservableCollection in your ViewModel, e.g. `ModulesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observableCollection);`.

Comment: Thanks and I have updated my code.

Comment: I have a suggested modification to your code, I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your ModulesView code, I suggest using an ObservableCollection to bind at this step `ModulesView = new ListCollectionView(sdb.GetModules())` instead of `sdb.GetModules()`.

```
public ICollectionView ModulesView
{
    get { return _ModulesView; }
    set
    {
        _ModulesView = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Module> myModulesList;

private void RefreshModule()
{
    myModulesList = new ObservableCollection<Module>(sdb.GetModules().OrderBy(mod => mod.Address));
    ModulesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myModulesList);
    ModulesView.Filter = obj =>
        {
            var Module = (Module)obj;
            return SelectedProduct != null && SelectedProduct.ModelNumber == Module.ModelNumber;
        };
}
```

Basically, if you ever want to update data and show the change in the datagrid, all you need to do is modify the ObservableCollection `myModulesList`.

And later, whenever you want to fill your `registerArray`, you can use:

```
registerArray = myModulesList.OrderBy(mod => mod.Address).Select(mod => mod.ParamValue).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply again. But I am kind of confuse how to write `TodayDispatchCollection`

Comment: @LeeBarry Ah, apologies, I missed that from part of my code which I copied, I'll edit.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry to borther you! what if I change the `ObservableCollection` to `DataSet`? How should I get the `ModulsView` in order? For details: [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643188/how-to-transfer-observablecollection-orderby-to-dataset)